# Roughly how long is a winning playthrough on Rogue?

Tags: rogue

I'm just wondering how long the game is if you finish it.

Ordinarily, you just die.

Comment: I've read the Meta about this issue, and I agree with the guy who says just pointing everyone to that site isn't good for this site.

Comment: Thing is, there's no real way to answer these questions in any definitive form.  Every player is different.  Some will take longer, complete everything, some will power through the main story.  Even those that follow the same path won't take the same amount of time.  We can either dupe them all to a single question (and just accumulate various methods of determining said information), or we can close them all as too broad, and they will eventually be deleted by the cleanup scripts.  This way, at least something survives.

Comment: I read that too, and I agreed with the guy who said we got some answers from people who had played the game through and gave good information.

Comment: Which is correct *for them*.  There's no guarantee that you'll take that long, or that anyone else will, either.  That's why these don't make for very good questions; interpretation is everything.

Comment: I agree that just pointing to HLTB isn't a great solution. I always get my expected playthrough times from there and from the the "hours on record" for positive reviews on Steam. Since Rogue isn't on Steam, I recommend just going with the HLTB. Although it only has two entries, both claim the same time.

Answer (score -1):

This question is open to a lot of variability, but howlongtobeat.com indicates that a single playthrough takes about 2.5 hours.

See http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=7945 for details.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I have no idea since it wasn't me.